# EXCEL Error Code?

Tags: cipher, humor

"What's wrong son?", asked Grandpa.

"Well. I was working in EXCEL and the page froze. Could not fix it. So I called Timmy the wiz kid from nextdoor. Asked him to fix it and tell me what the problem was. I went to get a cup of coffee. By the time I got back, the issue was fixed and  Timmy left a note that does not make any sense".  I said.

"Let me see" : Grandpa

He read it and started laughing.

The note said:

> u ran one five hundred ten t in EXCEL!

"You still don't get it son?" Said Grandpa.  No I don't. Do you?

This is from a joke I recently read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Timmy is telling you that

> u r an I D 10 T in Excel.

Comment: This was my first idea too, but I couldn't figure out the "five hundred" part. :)

Comment: Still not getting it, what does the answer mean? :/

Comment: @Luke yes, i know. This is not what I've asked though

Comment: @Luke can you please put your last comment in rot13 so others who want to solve it do not see the answer? Thanks.

Comment: I thought the ":/" at the end of QBrute's comment meant "actually, I know exactly what it means and am making a joke"...

Comment: @QBrute rot13(svir uhaqerq vf Q va Ebzna ahzrenyf?)